# CSS. Custom (x, y) positions for the each button from for-loop

Tags: css, button, for-loop, styles, position

So I have 24 buttons, now It looks like:
[image: looks like]

It should be something like this (I mean position of the buttons)
[image: should be]

Here is my button's code:

```
$info = getdate();
$date = $info['mday'];

for($i=1;$i<=24;$i++)
{
  if($i==$date)
  {
  Echo "<input type='button' class='imgClass'  onclick='issokantisLangas();' value='".$i."' src='deze.png'/>";
  }
  else
  {
  Echo "<input type='button' class='imgClass1' src='deze.png' value='".$i."' disabled />";
  }
}
```

Here is the CSS of the buttons:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .imgClass { 
    background-image: url(deze.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-size:100% 100%;
    width: 60px; 
    height: 60px; 
    border: 0px;
    color:#ed1c24;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
    }
    .imgClass:hover{ 
    background-position: 0px 0px; 
    border: 2px solid white;
    } 
    .imgClass:active{ 
    background-position: 0px 0px; 
    }
        .imgClass1 { 
    background-image: url(deze.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-size:100% 100%;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    width: 60px; 
    height: 60px; 
    border: 0px;
    color:#ed1c24;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
    }
</style>
```

When I change this line `margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;` with different numbers all the buttons move similar. I need to set for each button specific position. How to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the div which has the blue background and contains all the number boxes to have relative position using `position:relative;`, then the css of the number box imgClasses you have to add `position:absolute;` and when printing the  tags via php, add the custom position yourself. Take a look at the style in the following code:

```
for($i=1;$i<=24;$i++)
{
  if($i==$date)
  {
  Echo "<input type='button' style="top: 35px; right: 400px;" class='imgClass'  onclick='issokantisLangas();' value='".$i."' src='deze.png'/>";
  }
  else
  {
  Echo "<input type='button' style="top: 35px; right: 400px;" class='imgClass1' src='deze.png' value='".$i."' disabled />";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I misunderstood part about div with blue background which contains all the number boxes to have relative position. How to make that?

Comment: Yes, please refer to my implementation at JSFiddle, you could also hover on the 3-rd item:

http://jsfiddle.net/8e4Dn/15/

Please tell me if you don't understand something. This is not the smartest way to do it because people would do it using JavaScript instead, but since you asked how to do it with PHP, that's how you can do it

Comment: Could you help me to fix the code? As you gave me link here are divs in my case here are PHP, how to convert my php code to html with divs? And as you see here are for-loop which spawn 24 buttons, So I misunderstand how divs should work here? I need to create 24 divs or how? Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Ok, you are trying to make buttons that do something, but I propose that you use divs with links and attach the javascript to the links instead of making input form with buttons because they are harder to customize using CSS. Do the following:
echo "<div ...>";
echo "<a href='link.php' style='display:block; width:100%; height:100%;'>$i</a>";
echo "</div>";

Comment: Thank you I fixed It. When we talking about CSS, maybe do you know how correct include font with CSS? In Photoshop It is called BodoniSuper, font file: `BOD.TFF` in CSS I'm trying to use: `font-family: BOD;`, `font-family: BodoniSuper;` but all these ways incorrect. Thank you

Comment: Please open a separate issue on SO for this!